# Why is there nothing in Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

I was playing Pokemon Go in New York, but I did not find any Pokemon, Pokestops or Gyms. What happened?

Comment: Did you try restarting and/or uninstalling and reinstalling?

Answer (score 3):

There are can be multiple causes for this, as will be covered below:

1. You are traveling too fast. (This actually results in you being able to see Pokestops and Gyms, but you will not be able to collect anything from them or see any nearby pokemon.
2. The GPS could not locate you (i.e. if you are in the subway). If you can not be located by the GPS when the app opens, it will show a blank ground with no roads or anything.
3. You might be in a part of the city where there is nothing located there.
4. If all of the above does not apply, then you may want to contact support.

Answer (score 0):

those are likely root causes - the (works 99% of the time) solution is to force quit the app and restart.  if that doesn't work (at least 3 times) sign-out of your session, and log back in.
if all that fails, delete the app from your phone and download it again.  i personally haven't had to get to this step, but i quit/restart the app at least 6 times on average per day.  the app seems to get less and less stable with each new update release.